# SQL Server 2008 Table Maintenance - Rebuild, Reorganize, Update Stats, Check Integrity etc

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, maintenance

I'm migrating a ~15GB database from SQL Server 2005 to a new server running SQL Server 2008, and along with that I need to create all the new Maintenance Plans.  I can take care of all the backup stuff, but the table maintenance baffles me some.  Does anyone have any input on how often I should (or how often you do would suffice too) the following tasks?

- Check Database Integrity
- Rebuild Indexes
- Reorganize Indexes
- Update Statistics
- Shrink Database?

Am I missing anything? Again if you can share how often you do these tasks that would be great...and/or share any general information about your approach to table maintenance that would be helpful.  Lastly does it matter what order I run these tasks in (when setting up a job)?

Oh and I'm open to any links which might be of help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Usually you'd do weekly or daily depending on your usage and maintenance windows.

You pretty much never shrink, *especially* not scheduled.

For rebuild/reorganise and statistics there are scripts (such [as SQL Fool's one](https://web.archive.org/web/20171129184527/http://sqlfool.com/2011/06/index-defrag-script-v4-1)) that do a better job.
Note: reorganise and rebuild are not exclusive but work different ways. 3rd party scripts can choose the best option (based on fragmentation).

We use weekly index/DBCC and daily statistics. And never shrink.

From Simple-talk: [Don't Forget to Maintain Your Indexes](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/do-not-forget-to-maintain-your-indexes/)

Answer (score 4):

Re: Shrinking. I see so many people getting their claws out at the very mention of 'shrink' and 'database' in the same sentence, so time to clear things up a little.

Shrinking data is *baaaaad*. [It literally turns your indexes into quivering shells of their former glory](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/post/why-you-should-not-shrink-your-data-files.aspx). Don't do it.

Shrinking log should not be done routinely, but if you have a ridiculously outsized log (i.e. in one case I saw a 40GB log for a 100MB database, due to whoever set it up putting recovery model to full then never dumping the transaction log), you can shrink the log (**after** `BACKUP LOG`) to reclaim that space without any ill effects (although, obviously, the `SHRINK` will chew up I/O while it's running).

PS: Speaking of log files, check your log file size and autogrowth settings. Small autogrowth settings can lead to [underperforming log I/O](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/post/8-Steps-to-better-Transaction-Log-throughput.aspx) (due to a poorly-explained feature in SQL Server called [Virtual Log Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179355.aspx)), particularly on [batch transactions](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/linchi_shea/archive/2009/02/09/performance-impact-a-large-number-of-virtual-log-files-part-i.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

For scripts, [Ola Hallengren](http://ola.hallengren.com/) has wicked awesome things maintenance. Use maintenance plans for now, once you become a little comfortable with the process of doing maintenance, switch to using scripts, running scheduled SQL agent jobs.

At my place of work, I am doing DBCC, reorg'ing indexes every night. On the weekends, it's DBCC, rebuild indexes, update stats.

Don't shrink anything. If you do, [Brent Ozar](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2009/08/stop-shrinking-your-database-files-seriously-now/) will yell at you, it is never fun to have a SQL MCM yell at you.